# How to evaluate the definite integral $\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-at}dt$

Tags: definite-integrals

How to evaluate the following definite integral $\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-at}dt$.

Comment: Is $n$ an integer?

Comment: $n\in \mathcal{N}$ and $a>0$

Comment: What will be the value of the integral if $a=0$ ?

Comment: It will diverge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) is defined as
$$
\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
so substituting $t\mapsto t/a$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-at}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\frac1{a^n}\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac1{a^n}\Gamma(n)\\
&=\frac{(n-1)!}{a^n}\qquad\text{if $n$ is a positive integer}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Apply integration by parts repeatedly. Each time you do, the power of $t$ will drop by one. Assuming $n$ is an integer, this ends after $n-1$ repetitions .

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Check out [Gamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). And substitute $at=u$. I am assuming $a>0$ here.

Answer (score 2):

By integration by parts we get,

$$\int_0^{\infty}t^{n-1}e^{-at}dt=[-\frac{1}{a}t^{n-1}e^{-at}]_0^{\infty}+\frac{1}{a}\int_0^{\infty}(n-1)t^{(n-2)}e^{-at}dt$$ 
$$=[-\frac{1}{a}t^{n-1}e^{-at}]_0^{\infty}+[-\frac{1}{a^2}t^{n-1}e^{-at}]_0^{\infty}+\int_0^{\infty}(n-2)t^{(n-3)}e^{-at}dt$$
$$=...=\frac{(n-1)!}{a^{n-1}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-at}dt=\frac{(n-1)!}{a^{n}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Or directly$$\partial _{a}^{k}\int_{0}^{\infty }dt\exp [-at]=(-1)^{k}\int_{0}^{\infty
}dtt^{k}\exp [-at],$$where the left hand side is easily calculated.